# Is IJCA a valid open access journal?

Tags: research-process, publications, journals, open-access

Can someone let me know whether IJCA (http://www.ijcaonline.org/) is a valid open access journal to publish our research work?

BR,
Tharindu from Sri Lanka

Answer (score 10):

This journal is in [Beall's list](http://scholarlyoa.com/individual-journals/) of predatory journals, which is a strong indicator that you should **not** publish your work in this journal.  ([This question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/17379/what-are-fake-shady-and-or-predatory-journals) and its answers explain what a "predatory" journal is.)

You might also be interested in the answers to [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/101/how-do-you-judge-the-quality-of-a-journal), which describe how to evaluate the quality of a journal.