# Journal employees offering free publication in return for co-authorship and citations: is it a scam?

Tags: publications, publishers, disreputable-publishers

Some of my colleagues and I got offers from employees  of some reputed journal (not from journal itself), to publish our research paper for free, if:

- We include their name as co-author
- We use 60%+ citation of their journal (Doesn't it add up to IF??)

In return:

- It will be published completely free
- They will give us discount of some sort for next publication

Is it may be some kind of scam?

Comment: Also of interest: [What are "fake", "shady", and/or "predatory" journals?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/17379/what-are-fake-shady-and-or-predatory-journals)

Comment: I'm sorry that this comment will seem harsh but I really can't think of any other way to say it: anyone who thinks for even a microsecond that this might be a reasonable offer seriously needs to read up on publication ethics. If these people really were employees of the journal and the journal really was reputable, they would be fired as soon as the journal found out what they were doing.

Comment: Also, if that journal **is** reputed, I'd seriously think about forwarding that email to upper-level management person with short explanation about what's wrong. Such practices (I mean "include me as co-author") should be killed with fire.

Comment: What they are asking for is about as reasonable as telling you that they'll publish your paper only if you include a footnote with a joke about a priest, a rabbi, and a Buddhist monk who all walk into a bar and get into a mildly hilarious situation. Setting aside the issue of publication fees, the only thing that a serious journal should require is that the paper is good enough.

Comment: I agree with @quetzalcoatl: forward the mail to the official contact address(es) of the journal. They need to know.

Comment: You might wish to check [Beall's List](http://scholarlyoa.com/2014/01/02/list-of-predatory-publishers-2014/) to see if the journal in question is on this list of predatory/disreputable publishers.

Comment: Yes, It's in the list.

Comment: I find it concerning that you say 'some of my colleagues', which suggests at least three of you have got to the point of publishing without being able to see how obviously wrong this is. Unless you're all undergrads, which seems unlikely from the term 'colleagues', somewhere there's a supervisor that needs to add to their list of 'things to check all students know'.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

### This is a scam.

You are not the ones being scammed, however.  The editors are proposing to scam your readers, with your assistance, making you scammers as well.  Walk away before you damage your reputation.

Answer (score 48):

Whether or not this is a scam, it is **completely unethical**.

Under no circumstances is someone entitled to a publication credit in exchange for "free" publication of a paper. Don't forget that many reputable journals do **not** charge publication fees. It may be entirely possible for you to get your paper published without such an arrangement, which will be better for you, largely because any journal whose employees operate in such a manner isn't worth publishing in.

Answer (score 1):

Although this question has fully answered, just hear my point of view.

Have you ever asked yourself:

- What obligations those people have to fulfill their promises? After all they have not committed to the basic ethic matters.
- How are you going to claim the discount for your next publication?
- What kind of publication this journal hase made, that you want to cite 60%+ of them in your work?

If *you* claim anything after this, they easily ignore the whole deal. The only thing that they have in their mind is to rise up their reputation, by any means. Charging people for publishing and then offering them discounts with this method, is just a **scam**. It's more like paper-cooking.

Don't let yourself to be used.