# Is it possible to send the research to a local and international magazine?

Tags: publications

I am 21 years old and I sent a scientific research to a local  journal for youth, meaning it helps young people, and because my research in high school mathematics was sent to that journal, but now I study complex mathematics and understand it, and I want to write the same research, but with complex mathematics and complex concepts, and send it to an international journal. Is it possible?  Acceptance of a research paper from an international journal, even though I sent it to a local journal.

Comment: What does "local journal for youth" mean?  Is it just a school publication?  Something peer-reviewed?

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2893/attitudes-towards-self-plagiarism

Comment: Quite similar question: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/17374/how-can-i-withdraw-a-publication-from-a-predatory-fake-journal-and-resubmit-to

Comment: Do you have an advisor? It is them who would typically teach one how publishing works...

Answer (score 2):

In general, you can't send the *same* paper to two journals. There would be copyright issues among other things.

But if you write an extension of an older paper you can submit that to a different journal. Just be sure to cite the older work in the newer one and don't just incorporate parts of it. Quote and cite the older work just as you would the work of any other author.

The second journal will make a judgement, however, about whether the new paper is sufficiently advanced over the older one. If not, they would probably not be interested. Each new paper needs to make some "novel" contribution to the literature.