# How to handle payment requests from a predatory journal?

Tags: paper-submission, disreputable-publishers, fees

I sent an article to the journal at a promotional price. The article has already been published. They asked for a surcharge for the review and I paid but according to them I was late and they want to press me the membership fee. From the searches I know that this is a so-called predatory magazine. They have been writing to me for three days for payment. What steps can they take towards me? What will they do with my publication?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I withdraw a publication from a predatory (fake) journal and resubmit to a legitimate journal?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/17374/how-can-i-withdraw-a-publication-from-a-predatory-fake-journal-and-resubmit-to)

Comment: Any resolution of this yet?

Comment: Please do not vandalise your post.

Comment: Do not vandalize or change the question to be entirely different from what was originally asked. If you have a new question, submit a new post. Someone already answered your question: if you change it entirely, their answer won't make sense anymore! This is not a fair treatment of their time and effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not pay them anything else.

You can try asking for a refund.  I would be surprised if it works.

What will they do?  They will keep trying to get money from you.  It's tough to predict if they will put your manuscript on their website.